# Problems with a graph in R with tidyverse e ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, graph, tidyverse

I have a dataset called 'data' and I tried to make some graphs. but i have a problem with one in particoular.

[image: this is the image]

as you can see the the x axis is not right, how can I change that?

of course if you have other type of graphs but with the same 'concept', they're welcome

the dataset looks like this (adulti=adults, bambini=children, totale_pagato=price)

```
Events                 Date          adulti   bambini       totale_pagato
   <fct>                  <fct>      <fct>     <fct>           <dbl>
 1 "Ski Days "            08/01/2022   1        0                39  
 2 "Ski Days "            09/01/2022   1        0                42  
 3 "Ski Days "            09/01/2022   1        1                42  
 4 "Franciacorta Village" 06/01/2022   2        1                19.8
 5 "Ski Days "            06/01/2022   1        0                39  
 6 "Ski Days "            09/01/2022   1        0                42  
 7 "Ski Days "            09/01/2022   3        2               126  
 8 "Ski Days "            06/01/2022   2        0                86  
 9 "Ski Days "            09/01/2022   1        1                42  
10 "Ski Days "            06/01/2022   1        1                34
```

```
data %>% 
  group_by(adulti) %>% 
  mutate(mean = mean(totale_pagato),
         quantile = quantile(totale_pagato, probs = 0.9)) %>% 
  ungroup %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = c(mean, quantile), names_to = "summary_stat") %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = adulti, y = value, group = summary_stat)) +
  geom_jitter(aes(x = adulti, y = totale_pagato), inherit.aes = FALSE, alpha = 1/10) +
  geom_line(aes(lty = summary_stat, col = summary_stat)) +
  scale_colour_manual(values = c("orange", "red")) +
  labs(y = "trip.duration.hr")
```

this is the code I used, I would like something like this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your current problem is that `adulti` is formatted as `factor`. What you want to have in your case is a continuous variable. Try converting it to `as.integer` or `as.numeric`.
Alternatively you can adjust the levels of your factor if you are required to keep them as factors.

Comment: thanks, this worked for my code, now seems like a normale graph ahaha

Comment: It might be how the data set was imported. So you can avoid it by directly clarifying the format of the columns during the import. The reason it broke your graph is because `factors` are kind of like sorted `strings` and alphabetically `10`,  `11`, etc are before `2` just because the first character is `1`.